# Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot if usb hub is not attached to usbc port

Tags: boot, 22.04

I think this is happened after update Ubuntu base with Software Updater.

Without usb hub attached to usbc port before turning on the machine, the boot hang with B/W screen. The final message on the screen is:

```
loop22: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
```

However, if I attach usb hub to usbc port (it's bare usbhub, no device attach that that usbhub), I can boot and reach login screen very quickly. It doesn't matter what kind of usbhub (i.e. I test changing several usbhub) but it need to be attached before I turn on the power or before selection on grub menu.

Could anyone tell how can I fix this problem please? (Or how do I debug to get more info what is happening). I'm on HP Envy x360 machine.

UPDATE:

- Tired `boot-repair` doesn't solve the issue
- I think this happen after upgrade the BIOS as the issue appear when I try booting with live usb as well :(
- I can boot successfully without usbhub attached if I logon to windows first and restart to ubuntu (I've dual boot with Grub selection)

Comment: Boot Repair has nothing to do with it. If you're dual-booting with Windows then you must disable its Fast Startup feature and shutdown. Try that before any further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

I have an identical issue myself on envy x360 with the ryzen 5700u. Updating the kernel to `5.17.0-1018-oem` fixed that for me.

I went with probably the simplest possible route

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.17.0-1018-oem
sudo apt install grub-customizer
sudo grub-customizer
```

Then I went to "general settings" -> "default entry" -> "predefined", selected the option with the fresh kernel, and clicked "save"

Comment: Thanks man. It worked like a charm.