# Ubuntu 22.04.1 will not boot from USB stick

Tags: live-usb

I have a new HP TP01-2256 desktop, Intel i5 11400, 256GB M.2 SSD, 12GB RAM that will not start from USB stick in either normal Ubuntu or safe graphics mode.

I have tried with both Secure Boot & TPM enabled and disabled. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not start". If you can see the Grub menu then it is starting. What happens next?

Comment: what OS are you trying to boot from and how was the USB formed in the first place? If under ubuntu then use `Startup Disk Creator` utility. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO as per documentation? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 or whichever guide applies to your *unstated* 22.04.1 ISO as there are a few) and then write to media?  If you can't boot/verify it on this box; I'd suggest booting it on another box & performing the verification there of the media; if it fails to boot/verify on a second, even third device - the ISO was *faulty* or more likely [in my experience] if ISO validated; a bad write of ISO to media.  What validation did you do?

Comment: I forgot to say I tested this downloaded stick in a differrent uefi computer before and after the attempts to boot on HP TP01-2256 and it worked very well so it is not the usb stick problem

Comment: Booting a system does not prove media is good esp. if the hardware is not identical... Did you read/scan the logs & verify the media validation completed successfully, as if the hardware differs (ie. not another HP TP01-2256) or you do different things its possible different areas of the media were being used/read; reading the media validation scan report will verify the media is good is useful as the validation reads all of the media.

Comment: Yes, I get the grub menu and I can can pick Ubuntu or safe graphics,but after I click on one or the other the screen goes black for 5min. I stopped timing the because Ubuntu 22.04.1 was running and on internet by 3 min. 30 sec.

Comment: It would be interesting to test if the problem depends on the graphics or something else. One way is to test with Ubuntu Server, the same version 22.04.1 LTS alias jammy, or the next version kinetic to be released in October as 22.10. Kinetic has a newer kernel with newer kernel drivers, that might manage the hardware in your new computer. You can try to *extract and clone from compressed image files to the USB stick* according to [this link to the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692), and check if your computer boots to a text screen with a working Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on my HP box. Weirdly enough, plugging in a usb hub fixed it. Here's someone else who is facing a similar issue:
[Ubuntu 22.04 won't boot if usb hub is not attached to usbc port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420076/ubuntu-22-04-wont-boot-if-usb-hub-is-not-attached-to-usbc-port)

Comment: Not an answer to send the OP to anther question.